# Undefined reference error while using PCL 1.8 with ROS Indigo

Tags: c++, pcl, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to use PCL 1.8 with ROS Indigo but getting *Undefined reference error*.

The PCL 1.8 is installed to a local directory from the source and it is working fine standalone. However, I am trying to use it in one of my ROS packages. Please see below *CMakeLists.txt*-

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test_package)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  sensor_msgs
  pcl_ros
  pcl_conversions
)

set(PCL_FOLDER /home/baxterpc/Tools/pcl/release)
find_package(PCL 1.8 REQUIRED PATHS ${PCL_FOLDER} NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

MESSAGE(STATUS "PCL_VERSION: " ${PCL_VERSION})

add_library(sphere_detector src/sphere_detector.cpp)
target_link_libraries(sphere_detector ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable (sphere_detector_test src/sphere_detector_test.cpp)
target_link_libraries (sphere_detector_test sphere_detector ${PCL_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

During compilation, it is showing *PCL_VERSION: 1.8.1.99*. Below is the error reported while running *catkin_make*-

```
[100%] Building CXX object test_package/CMakeFiles/sphere_detector_test.dir/src/sphere_detector_test.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable /home/baxterpc/ros_ws/devel/lib/test_package/sphere_detector_test
CMakeFiles/sphere_detector_test.dir/src/sphere_detector_test.cpp.o: In function `pcl::Feature<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::Normal>::initCompute()':
sphere_detector_test.cpp:(.text._ZN3pcl7FeatureINS_11PointXYZRGBENS_6NormalEE11initComputeEv[_ZN3pcl7FeatureINS_11PointXYZRGBENS_6NormalEE11initComputeEv]+0x1b8): undefined reference to `pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB, pcl::KdTreeFLANN<pcl::PointXYZRGB, flann::L2_Simple<float> > >::KdTree(bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/baxterpc/ros_ws/devel/lib/test_package/sphere_detector_test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [test_package/CMakeFiles/sphere_detector_test.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 Bit PC. I want to know how to use PCL 1.8 inside ROS Indigo. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282586/undefined-reference-error-while-using-pcl-1.8-with-ros-indigo/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note: I'm not saying this is the cause of your issue, but you'll have to recompile all pkgs that depend on PCL from source anyway, you cannot mix the two versions.

---

Have you recompiled all pkgs that depend on PCL (`pcl_conversions`, `pcl_ros`, etc) from source using your custom PCL version (in `/home/baxterpc/Tools/pcl/release`)? If not, it could be your mixing PCL 1.7 with 1.8.x lib sets.

---

> No. I haven't. Can you please tell me the steps to recompiled all packages that depend on PCL?

The most fool-proof method I know is:

1. deinstall all packages that depend on `libpcl-1.7-all` *and* all `libpcl-*-1.7` packages themselves (removing `libpcl-1.7-all` will probably already take those pkgs with it)
2. create a catkin workspace (or reuse what you already have), clone the [perception_pcl](https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl) repository in it
3. make sure to install all dependencies (but make sure to ask `rosdep` to ignore the `libpcl-all-dev` dependency (as it will try to make `apt` install `v1.7`, which we don't want)
4. build the workspace (regular `catkin_make` or `catkin build`)

If you have any packages you deinstalled in step 1 but do still want/need, you'll have to build those from source in your catkin workspace as well (as all binary pkgs will try to use PCL 1.7).

See also #q252478 for the general workflow for building pkgs from sources.

Note that you'll have to make sure that `/home/baxterpc/Tools/pcl/release` is on the library/pkg search path, or you'll get errors on step 4, as no PCL can be found.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-13**:
No. I haven't. Can you please tell me the steps to recompiled all packages that depend on PCL? Thank you very much.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-14**:
Thank you very much. I tried to remove `libpcl-1.7-all` using [synaptic package manager](http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/) but I stopped in between. Since it was showing the complete removal of  `libpcl-1.7-all`  is going to remove `ros-indigo-desktop-full` package. See [here](https://goo.gl/fcYwm5).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
well, yes, that is to be expected. If you want to do this right, you'll have to remove those packages and build them from sources, or you run the risk programs crashing with `SEGFAULT`s etc.

You can try to do what I described without removing the PCL 1.7 pkgs, but you'll have to be very careful.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-14**:
An alternative might be to use a suitable Docker container for this.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-02-14**:
Thank you very much.